# The project from AndroidStudio doesn't run on phone (but runs on emulator!)

Tags: android, eclipse, import, device, android-studio-import

I am novice-freelancer and i have executed the project in Eclipse. Then I have recreated the project in Android Studio as it was required by the hirer. The hirer says that the project doesn't run on his phones (Samsung note 3 and huawei honor 6), but it works on emulator and perfectly runs on my devices. When I play the project through teamviewer Android Studio shows Device selection window, the logcut shows no mistake. I am so stressed and confused... What should i check? Does the hirer say truth to me? The hirer says that even already generated apk can't be opened... Please, help, i am so disappointed.

Comment: You should get more details. Does it not install, and if not, what is the error message? Does it crash?

Comment: yeah... the thing is no crash message as he says..

Comment: OK, well, does the app start? What's shown on the screen? The details are important.

Comment: thank your for participation. actually it works now. the potential decisions were 1. rebooting the computer 2. updating Android Studio for the same version. 3. miracle :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the drivers of the device are properly installed and USB debugging is enabled on the device. Try restarting if it still doesn't work. The problem is mainly due to improper installation of device driver.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll check it if the hirer allows me to do that. The hirer says that only my project doesn't run on his devices. Is that possible?

Comment: What version of android did you choose before creating the project? Try to keep it below 4.1 so that it'll be compatible with >90% devices.

Comment: I have chosen 3.0 as minimum SDK version